# laravel 4.2 mysql database creation from phpmyadmin without using migrations

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

i tried it and it says that data base was connected, we can do queries too.

```
Route::get('database-test', function(){
    if(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName()){
        echo 'connected'.DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();

    }
});

Route::get('staff', function(){
    $results = DB::select('select * from users where staff_id = ?', array(1));
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($results);
    print_r($results[0]) ;

    echo '</pre>';
});
```

these routes were ok.
but when try to use codes like following,

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get();

foreach ($users as $user)
{
    var_dump($user->name);
}
```

it gives errors.

please help me to solve my problem.
thanks in advance

Comment: what error are you gettin?

Comment: i solved it ujwal :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey in your Routes use your code its working perfect

```
Route::get('staff', function(){
$users = DB::table('users')->get();

foreach ($users as $user)
{
    var_dump($user->name);
}

});
```

you will get output :) working for me :)

Comment: if you run your project migrate your project if its done then insert some dummy data its should work

Comment: hey @NimmiRashinika if my answer helped you mark as correct answer :)